# comment code in MVC5 web.config in debug mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, web.config-transform

When I deployed my app I had to add following code to my `web.config` file because otherwise the server won't display my `.svg` file

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
    </staticContent>
<system.webServer>
```

However, if I leave that bit of code in the file while I develop on my machine, it leads to weird errors (e.g., my machine doesn't load my `.css` file anymore). All works fine if I comment that out again while working locally.

But exactly that is a hastle, commenting/uncommenting that code always when developing resp. deploying.

**So my two questions:**

1) Is there a way to include code conditionally in the `web.config`, e.g., depending on if degug or release build, or if deploying?

2) Why is that code causing trouble on my local machine in the first place?

**UPDATE:** So Q1 is answered, but still looking for an answer to Q2! Can't accept an answer before that ...

Answer (score 1):

In your web.config File you have an arrow that points to two other Files called `Web.Release.config` and `Web.Debug.config` there you can make such changes. There you can modify your web.config based on your Run Mode.

There is a very good Microsoft Article about it im pretty sure it will help you

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd465326(VS.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks. While I will have a look at that, You didn't answer my 2nd question.